# Magento product meta data to be same as product description

Tags: magento, product, meta

I am very new to Magento and one of the tasks on hand is to use the existing product description as the meta data. As the site has over 600 products it does not make sense to add the meta data manually. Can I please get some advice on how this can be done? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check product view block (`app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php`), you'll see that in the prepare layout method, Magento uses product name and description for keywords and meta description if meta data is not set.

So if modules haven't overwritten this block, you should be fine. :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will check this

Comment: @Stefe: Any luck?

Comment: You were right. I didnt have to do anything. Thanks heaps for the help

Comment: That's nice to hear. :) Don't forget to mark correct answer as it will help others who might have similar problem. ;)